# Is it possible to encrypt the source code

Tags: security, encryption

I'm developing a web application for my private use. I want to hide my source code from search engines and other bots/ rippers. Is it possible to encrypt the code for hiding it from search engines and to prevent fro rippers/hackers.

Comment: Encrypt in what way?

Comment: i want to make it hide is there any way

Comment: I dont understand the question, what do you want to hide - exactly?

Comment: i want to hide my site from bots, search engine, simply said this should be accessed by entering the domain address

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding about how the web works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you're putting the web application on the internet then the short answer is no.

The browser needs to read your source code in plaintext in order to render the page.

There are a few things you can do to make it more difficult for humans to read your source code, and they are well outlined here: [How-to-Hide-your-Source-Code](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/article.php/3875651/Web-Developer-Class-How-to-Hide-your-Source-Code.htm), but please realize these techniques will likely make your code base more difficult to maintain.

If you're concerned about someone ripping or stealing your work, then a safe bet is to avoid putting it online in the first place.